# Error when opening workbook by using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried several ways to open a separate workbook in one workbook, but always get error message Application-defined or object-defined error, the following is my code:

```
Sub PrepaidImport()
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, vals As Variant, MyFile1 As String, MyFile2 As String
MyFile1 = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set x = Workbooks.Open(MyFile1)
End Sub
```

the following code get the same error as well:

```
Sub PrepaidImport()
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, vals As Variant, MyFile1 As String, MyFile2 As String
Set x = Workbooks.Open("M:\Company\2014\YTD 2014 Prepaid Assets.xlsx")
End Sub
```

The following code get a diff error because I'm trying to open a binary workbook:

```
Sub PrepaidImport()
Dim y as Workbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Y:\Branch\Prepaid Assets Amortization Import Template.xlsb")
End Sub
```

This is my entire code:

```
Sub PrepaidImport()
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, vals As Variant, MyFile1 As String, MyFile2 As String

Set x = Workbooks.Open("M:\Company\2014\YTD 2014 Prepaid Assets.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Y:\Branch\Prepaid Assets Amortization Import Template.xlsb")

vals = x.Worksheets("11.2014").Range("A6", "A" &x.Worksheets("11.2014").Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Value
Set y.Worksheets("Journal_Details").Range("Y1").Value = vals

x.Close

End Sub
```

The files are opened, but error message pops out and makes me unable to run the subsequent code. I'm on Excel 2007.

Please help!

Comment: If "The files are opened", on what line is the error occuring?

Comment: It's right after the file opens the message pops up, and stops at set x= Workboks.Open(MyFile1) in my 1st example

Comment: Is `PrepaidImport()` called from somewhere, and/or what is the subsequent code trying to do? And do you have the code running from `activeworkbook`?

Comment: I just tested `filePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value: Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)` and it works when the `workbook` calling the code is `active`, but get the `1004` error when it's not `active`

Comment: No, PrepaidImport() is totally independent on a blank excel spreadsheet, and the subsequent code is trying to copy range from one spreadsheet to another opened spreadsheet, and I am having the code running from this blank active workbook

Comment: It is active, actually I created a button and assigned this piece of macro to it

Comment: If you delete all the other code and just run `PrepaidImport()` do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, only running PrepaidImport() still get the error

Comment: How about if you remove the lines after `Set y = Workbooks.open...`?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that as well, and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second to last line, you shouldn't have the "set" statement in front of the assignment line, i.e.  it should just be

```
y.Worksheets("Journal_Details").Range("Y1").Value = vals
```